# Multi Series Highchart Data with Multidimensial Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, highcharts

I am trying to get my data array in a format that is used by Highcharts to generate a multi-series chart of the data.

My data array is:

```
Array ( 
[answer1] => Array ( [SubQuestion 1] => 3 [SubQuestion 2] => 1 ) 
[answer2] => Array ( [SubQuestion 1] => 2 [SubQuestion 2] => 2 ) 
[answer3] => Array ( [SubQuestion 1] => 1 [SubQuestion 2] => 1 ) 
[answer4] => Array ( [SubQuestion 1] => 1 [SubQuestion 2] => 2 ) 
[answer5] => Array ( [SubQuestion 1] => 0 [SubQuestion 2] => 1 )
)
```

I need to get it into this format for Highcharts:

```
$chartdata = array(
array("name" =>"SubQuestion 1","data"=>  array(3,2,1,1,0) ),
array("name" =>"SubQuestion 2","data"=>  array(1,2,1,2,1) )
);
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to how to iterate through my array to create a new array in the HighCharts format?

Thanks for all the help. I just wanted to close the loop and post the slightly modified version of the correct answer:
        $chartdata = array();
        foreach($series as $key1 => $value1){
            $i=0;
            foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
                $chartdata[$i]['name'] = $key2;
                $chartdata[$i]['data'][] = $value2;
                $i++;
            }
                }

Comment: why not just create it using foreach and then create your desired array?

Comment: I'd look at `array_walk()` to modify initial array. But transforamtion of initial array to desired output is not obvious, so maybe you'll have to use `foreach` and create a new transformed array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myarray = Array ( 
'answer1' => Array ( 'SubQuestion 1'=> 3 , 'SubQuestion 2' => 1 ) ,
'answer2'=> Array ( 'SubQuestion 1' => 2, 'SubQuestion 2' => 2 ) ,
'answer3' => Array ( 'SubQuestion 1' => 1, 'SubQuestion 2' => 1 ) ,
'answer4' => Array ( 'SubQuestion 1' => 1, 'SubQuestion 2' => 2 ) ,
'answer5' => Array ( 'SubQuestion 1' => 0, 'SubQuestion 2' => 1 )
);


$temp = array();
$chartdata = array();
foreach($myarray as $key1 => $value1){
  foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
   if(!in_array($key2, $temp)){
    $temp[] = $key2;
   }
   $chartdata[array_search($key2, $temp)]['name'] = $key2;
   $chartdata[array_search($key2, $temp)]['data'][] = $value2;
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($chartdata);
```

Comment: That is very close to what i need.

    Array ([SubQuestion 1] =>Array ( [name] => SubQuestion 1 [data] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 ) ) 

[SubQuestion 2] => 
Array ( [name] => SubQuestion 2 [data] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 ) )
 )

However there is an extra 'Key'.  the data should be a numerical array not an associative array